# Where are Java's native methods defined?

Tags: java, linux, networking, java-native-interface, native-code

I have the 64-bit linux distro of the JRE (1.6_34) installed installed on a CentOS server. I pulled down the source code and drilled down into the `java.net.SocketInputStream` class.

That class has a method called `socketRead0`:

```
/** 
 * Reads into an array of bytes at the specified offset using
 * the received socket primitive. 
 * @param fd the FileDescriptor
 * @param b the buffer into which the data is read
 * @param off the start offset of the data
 * @param len the maximum number of bytes read
 * @param timeout the read timeout in ms
 * @return the actual number of bytes read, -1 is
 *          returned when the end of the stream is reached. 
 * @exception IOException If an I/O error has occurred.
*/
private native int socketRead0(FileDescriptor fd, 
        byte b[], int off, int len, int timeout)
        throws IOException;
```

Where can I find the native source code that gets executed when this `SocketInputStream#socketRead0` method is executed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would need to download the JVM source to find the corresponding native code which implements `socketRead0`.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the other answers, `native` methods are actually C functions, invoked through [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/). The library files containing the C functions are usually loaded with `System.loadLibrary` and exports that follow the JNI naming scheme (prefixed with `Java_`, followed by the package, the class and the method name, with underscores instead of dots) are automatically linked to those `native` Java methods.

However, the other answers don't mention a second way to link C functions to `native` Java methods: [RegisterNatives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17734). This interface can be used to provide C implementations without ever calling `System.loadLibrary`, using the JNI naming scheme or even exporting those functions.

Comment: +1 for RegisterNatives (thanks for the info, did not know this), but *"The DLLs"* This question is tagged *linux*.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenJDK it is [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6-gate/jdk/file/0d99d61882b7/src/windows/native/java/net/SocketInputStream.c)   For some reason I cant find the Linux implementation. Typically search for a native folder. Your file will be in it

Comment: Thanks @jogabonito (+1) - perhaps here: `<myJavaHome>/jdk/1.6.34/jdk1.6.0_34/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so`?

Answer (score 0):

A `native` method indicates this method is not Java code, but *native* code -a.k.a. machine code- and usually written in C/C++. Calls to such functions is made through [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

You should search for where it loads the native libraries it uses, which looks like

```
System.loadLibrary("nameOfLibrary");
```

This native library should export functions for Java like

```
JNIEXPORT returnType JNICALL Java_ClassName_methodName
```

Comment: Thanks @m0skit0 (+1) - where would I find this call to `System.loadLibrary`?

Comment: I might guess that class should do it, but I really don't know. Do a search on the source.

Comment: The JVM doesn't load all its own native code. Much of it is already part of the JVM.

Comment: your java class should have the loadLibrary call as a part of  static block,and corresponding dll or shared object should be avialable.

Comment: Thanks @EJP (+1) - please see my comment underneath jogabonito's answer - I have the same question for you!